# Populating a table by combining the top n rows from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, simplified to the following:

```
users:
+-----+------+-----------+
| id  | name | timestamp |
+-----+------+-----------+

vouchers:
+-----+------+
| id  | code |
+-----+------+
```

I also have a third table, containing pairs of IDs:

```
recipients:
+-----+------+------+
| id  | u_id | v_id |
+-----+------+------+
```

I need to periodically insert new pairs of IDs to the recipients table when a user's row is older than two weeks (the query will be scheduled to run once a day). IDs already present within the recipients table should not be retrieved.

I am currently unable to find an effective method of returning arbitrarily paired IDs from the two initial SELECT queries:

```
1. SELECT id FROM users WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND id not in (select u_id from recipients)

2. SELECT id FROM vouchers WHERE id not in (select v_id from recipients) limit *by number of retrieved user IDs*
```

So far, all of my attempted JOINS have failed to achieve the desired result. I have established a solution using the two above queries, with a PHP for loop to pair the results before their insertion, but I am very aware that this is poor.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's unclear what pairs you are adding. For every user that is greater than 2 weeks old, is it adding one recipient pair for *every* not-already-assigned voucher in the system?

Comment: No. You're talking about a cartesian product? With every user paired paired with every voucher? The following metaphor might help: Users are in a queue, those at the front are let though a turnstyle, and they are given a single voucher as they pass.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Cartesian Product and remove the combinations already present in `Recipients` using a `NOT EXISTS`

[Cartesian Product](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).

```
SELECT *
FROM   users u
       , vouchers v
WHERE  u.timestamp < NOW() -INTERVAL 2 WEEK
       AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    Recipients r
         WHERE   r.u_id = u.id
                 AND r.v_id = v.id
       )
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what I need. I don't need to pair _every_ user with _every_ voucher. I need to pair every user with _a single_ voucher, and then ensure that each voucher is exclusive to a single user.

Comment: @user1177756 - and how do you determine wich user get wich voucher?

Comment: I don't, it's not a requirement. Any user could be paired with any voucher... WAIT! I think I've just overlooked a _very_ simple thing, in fact at first glance I feel something of an idiot. I should just pair each user ID (eg, 53) with it's equivalent voucher id (again, 53). This way each user will receive one voucher, and each voucher will only be used once... Sorry, long day.

Comment: @user1177756 - don't worry, been there :)